# Terminal doesn't understand some easy commands and keeps trying to install package 'sed' after trying to add directory to PATH

Tags: shell-script, sed, path, vi

Learning linux so I wrote a simple script to test different scripting variables and arguments. Tried adding the directory to my PATH, something went wrong. I can't even use the ls command...

I have no clue what happened, please explain to me how this happened and how to fix it. Thank you[image: Bash Shell]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First about the PATH variable.

I would recommend this setup:

```
mkdir ~/scripts
echo 'export PATH=/home/jack/scripts:${PATH}' >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
```

I don't think adding ~/Documents to the PATH is a best practice. Adding export clause to the .bashrc makes it permanent. Curly braces isolate variable name from the surrounding text. Variable names are case sensitive.

So when you did

```
PATH=$path:~/Documents
```

you virtually destroyed your PATH, since $path is considered different variable and it most likely was not set. I am not exactly sure, but shell could also try to interpret the rest of the line as a variable name.

```
PATH=${PATH}:~/Documents
```

would have worked.

The easiest way to fix your situation, I think, is to log out and login again. This will set PATH to default value.

Comment: Also, there is no need to log out. Just start a new terminal.

Comment: @Kusalananda True that! I've changed the answer to use single quotes, it will not expand PATH in-line this way.

Comment: The `export` will usually have been taken care of already by the system login scripts; no need to export again.